# Github repo for MacTeX/TeXShop documentation?

Tags: texshop, mactex

I would like to make some readability/usability improvements in [READ_ME_FIRST](https://tug.org/mactex/READ_ME_FIRST.pdf), but could not find a reference to the GitHub (or something else?) repo.
Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can contact the maintainers of this document on one of the MacTeX mailing lists. Most of the documents distributed from tug.org are not in a git repo on a public git hoster (some are in the TeX Live SVN).

Comment: The TeX on MacOS mailing list is the best route, or email Dick Koch directly.